# What is the difference between an Image and a Sprite in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

In the Phaser 3 docs I can see that the biggest difference between `Sprite` and `Image` is that you cannot animate or add a physics body to an `Image`, but in `Image` properties you can see an animationManager. I'm a little confused about this. Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 15):

Actually, according to the official docs [`Phaser.GameObjects.Image`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Image.html) does not have a `AnimationManager` property.

[`Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#anims__anchor) on the other hand does have an `anims` that can access animations, but doesn't include a direct property of type `AnimationManager`. Both can be confirmed by using the TypeScript defintions.

This is because `AnimationManager` is global, and handles all animations. In Phaser 2 all objects would handle their own animations. See for example Phaser 2 CE's [`Phaser.Image` docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Image.html#animations).

So just as the documentation says, `Image` is effectively a static, lighter-weight, `Sprite`.